# How to obtain twitter user and place data from tweets with tweepy.Paginator

Tags: python, tweepy

I am using tweepy to get data from tweets. I managed to get the main tweet items, such as `'id', 'author_id'`. However, I struggle to get the user and place items from `user_fields` and `place_fields`.

I expected `tweet.includes["users"]` or `tweet.includes["places"]` to give me access to these items, but alas.

Note, the example is conservative: it requests 10 tweets at the time, times 2, resulting in a limit of 20 tweets in total.

```
import tweepy
import time
client = tweepy.Client("MYSECRETTOKEN")
# query to search for tweets
query = '"Matariki" lang:en'  

start_time = "2022-06-23T22:00:00.000Z"  
end_time =   "2022-06-26T22:00:00.000Z"

paginator = tweepy.Paginator(client.search_all_tweets,
                      query=query,
                      start_time=start_time,
                      end_time=end_time,
                      tweet_fields=['id', 'author_id',  "created_at", "text", "source", 'lang', 'in_reply_to_user_id', 'conversation_id', 'public_metrics', 'referenced_tweets', 'reply_settings'],
                      user_fields=["name", "username", "location", "verified", "description", "created_at"],
                      place_fields=['full_name', 'id', 'country', 'country_code', 'geo', 'name', 'place_type'],
                      expansions='author_id,geo.place_id',
                      max_results=10)

#%%

# Loop the paginator, and throttle the request to not offend Twitter

tel = 0
for tweet in paginator.flatten(limit=20): # Total number of tweets to retrieve
    tel +=1
    print(tweet.text, tel, '\n')
    if tel%10 == 0:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`tweepy.Paginator.flatten` returns `Tweet` objects, which do not have `includes` data attached to them.

Instead, you want to read the responses directly returned by `tweepy.Paginator`, which will include a `data` field with a list of `Tweet` objects, along with additional fields like `meta` and `includes`.

```
# coding: utf-8
import os
import tweepy

if __name__ == "__main__":
    twitter_token = os.environ["TWITTER_TOKEN"]

    twitter = tweepy.Client(
        bearer_token=twitter_token,
        wait_on_rate_limit=True)

    query = '"Matariki" lang: en'
    start_time = "2022-06-23T22:00:00.000Z"
    end_time = "2022-06-26T22:00:00.000Z"

    # Most of us don't have access to the 'search_all_tweets'
    # endpoint, so I switched to the 'search_recent_tweets'
    # for this example
    paginator = tweepy.Paginator(
        twitter.search_recent_tweets,
        query=query,
        start_time=start_time,
        end_time=end_time,
        tweet_fields=["id", "author_id",  "created_at", "text", "source", "lang", "in_reply_to_user_id", "conversation_id", "public_metrics", "referenced_tweets", "reply_settings"],
        user_fields=["name", "username", "location", "verified", "description", "created_at"],
        place_fields=["full_name", "id", "country", "country_code", "geo", "name", "place_type"],
        expansions="geo.place_id,author_id",
        max_results=10,
        limit=10
      )

    for rsp in paginator:
        print(f"Included Places: {rsp.includes.get('places')}")
        print(f"Included Users: {rsp.includes.get('users')}")
        print("-" * 80)
```

And the results look like this...

```
Included Places: [<Place id=07d9dd109e080000 full_name=Te Wharewaka o Poneke>]
Included Users: [<User id=136324666 name=Steph username=StephJ2731>, <User id=1018242338278256640 name=M T Bashir username=MBashir48666504>, <User id=1103426302537695233 name=Emily username=emilyalexrado>, <User id=55514340 name=Manaiakalani Cluster username=clusternz>, <User id=2671939628 name=Traci Houpapa MNZM JP CFInstD username=TraciHoupapa>, <User id=298390513 name=ZarahnSouthon username=ZarahnSouthon>, <User id=1850936329 name=lynnwoodprice username=lynnwoodprice>, <User id=275843300 name=Kevin Veale username=krveale>, <User id=1495585940034580480 name=Apollo username=apollonz1>]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Included Places: None
Included Users: [<User id=28025094 name=1. Matthew Reweti for Te Whanganui-a-Tara username=poneke_matt>, <User id=18541658 name=Sina Brown-Davis username=uriohau>, <User id=25228534 name=Rangimārie ✌ username=Amonish>, <User id=79055874 name=AklBotanicGrdns username=AklBotanicGrdns>, <User id=21252945 name=Tara username=tarasutherland>, <User id=138197586 name=Flawed by design username=RiversAwarau>, <User id=1100256089830961152 name=Hobsonville Point Public Transport User username=PointUser>, <User id=286644799 name=Sober Lady username=soberlady1998>, <User id=2831083298 name=Whānau Ora Commissioning Agency username=WhanauOraAgency>]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hi, just tried, but it does not work with `search_all_tweets` resulting in an overflow `TooManyRequests: 429 Too Many Requests Too Many Requests`

Comment: @MartienLubberink - `TooManyRequests` means you're hitting your API rate limit - I updated the code to add [`wait_on_rate_limit=True`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client) which may fix it.

Comment: Alas, the response is now: Rate limit exceeded. Sleeping for 900 seconds

Comment: @MartienLubberink - 900s = 15 minutes, which is the [standard API window limit for Twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/rate-limits). I imagine whatever you're doing is just exhausting all your requests possible.

Comment: I tried this code with search_all_tweets  but it gives an error saying KeyError: 'includes'

Comment: @VishalKharde This code does not do error checking if you get tweets that don't have place or user information attached to them.